# When constructor chaining, which constructor should the others call?

Tags: java, object-oriented

When I have a class with multiple constructors where one constructor calls another one (constructor chaining), which constructor should be the one that all the other constructors call eventually?

Here's an example where the "all args" constructor calls the "no args" constructor:

```
class Goblin {
    // always starts at 10
    private int strength;
    private String name;

    public Goblin() {
        this.strength = 10;
    }

    public Goblin(String name) {
        this();
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Here's an example where the "no args" constructor calls the "all args" constructor

```
class Goblin {
    // always starts at 10
    private int strength;
    private String name;

    public Goblin() {
        this(null);
    }

    public Goblin(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.strength = 10;
    }
}
```

The idea is that there should be 1 place where `this.strength = 10` and it won't have to be copied.  Which of these is best?

Comment: If you use an instance variable initializer, you won't need constructor chaining, at least for this example.  The next step would be to have a constructor that offers a strength parameter, then you might entertain constructor chaining.

Comment: Right.  For this example, it could be just `private int strength = 10;`.  I was just using that logic as a stand-in for potentially more complicate logic, e.g. setting up internal arrays for a hash table implementation that takes a `capacity` argument, so we can't simply use an instance initializer there.

Comment: How about separating the concerns of initialization of data and of allocating the components necessary for the object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would advocate for preferring the second approach, as this allows you to declare both members as `final` and make the class formally immutable.

Comment: Good point about the immutability.  And it seems this would be true even if we had, say, `Goblin(int)`, `Gobling(String)`, and the "all args" constructor as `Goblin(int, String)`.  If we don't want to expose the "all args" constructor, we can just make it private I guess.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it doesn't matter. The important thing is to chain the constructors so you're not repeating code. But if the no-arg one calls the one with arguments, or the one with args calls the no-arg one, they both accomplish the same thing - creating a (valid) object with no code repetition.

Answer (score 2):

Your first approach only works as long as your default values and the default values for the datatype match.

If for example all goblins constructed with an empty constructor should be named "John", you need the second approach, otherwise you have `this.name =` in your code twice.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the constructor with more args. This is called Constructor Delegation in C++ and the purpose it to reuse as much code as possible.

Comment: Having everything call the "no args" constructor also re-uses code, though.  Or, if there's a 1-arg and a 2-arg constructor, the 2-arg one can call the 1-arg one and the 1-arg one can call the no arg one.